# Finding k using the Central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

In a swamp there are two regular frogs and three princes frogs, the queen takes out $k$ frogs with replacement. Let $R$ be the number of times that a regular frog is selected.

> Using the Central Limit Theorem, evaluate the minimal number k such that the probabilty of selecting a regular frog at most  $50\%$ of the time will be at least $0.99$.

My attempt:

$R\sim B(n,p)\;\;\;,\;\;\;$ 
$R\sim B(k,\frac25)\;\;\;,\;\;\;$
$E[R]=\boxed{\frac{2k}{5}}\;\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;$

$$P(X \leq x)\approx \Phi\bigg(\frac{x\text{-np}}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\bigg)$$

$$P(X \leq 0.5k)\approx \Phi\bigg(\frac{0.5k-\frac{2k}5}{\sqrt{k\frac25\frac35}}\bigg)=\Phi\bigg(\frac{0.1k}{\sqrt{k\frac6{25}}}\bigg)\leq0.99$$

$$P\big(\big|R-\frac{2k}{5}\big| \geq \alpha\big)\leq \frac{6k}{25 \alpha ^2}$$

$$\frac{0.1k}{\sqrt{\frac{6k}{25}}}\stackrel{\text{table}}=2.326\bigg/()^2$$

$$\frac{0.01k^2}{\frac{6k}{25}}=5.41$$

$$0.01k^2=1.298k$$

$$k=\lceil129.8\rceil=\boxed{130}$$

> Is it correct so far?

Comment: Looks good to me!  Note:  I edited the text a bit, take a look and make sure I didn't change your meaning.  Your solution looks entirely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use $X$ and $R$ interchangeably (you should stick with $R$). You appear also not to have performed a continuity correction on moving from binomial to normal.

Notice that the line where you state the CLT doesn't actually justify your answer: if you let $\alpha = 4$, you see that the CLT only tells you that $R$ has probability $\leq 1.83$ of being more than $4$ away from the mean, but that's a useless statement. In particular, since the true answer according to Mathematica is that $122$ is the first $k$ for which selecting a regular frog at most 50% of the time is more than 99% likely, something is certainly wrong.

```
Select[Probability[X <= 1/2 #, 
 X \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[#, 2/5]] > 99/100 &]@
Range[125]
```

I re-did the calculations using the appropriate continuity correction, and obtained 120 as the answer, which is closer but still no cigar. The relevant probabilities are within 0.05% of each other: the probability according to the normal approximation at $k = 120$ is 0.990077, while the true probability is 0.98954.

This answer is less concrete than I would like, sadly, because I don't know of a way to fix the answer.